# Как называется кодировка?

Tags: кодировка

Как называется такая кодировка?

```
\320\240\321\203\321\201\321\201\320\272\320\270\320\271\321\202\320\265\320\272\321\201\321\202
```

Если ли сервисы (или библиотеки) перекодировки, например, в utf8 (в C/C++ библиотеки)?

Comment: А какой, предположительно, язык? И вообще, откуда это?

Comment: Могу поспорить, это восьмеричное представление.

Comment: это надпись по русски "Русский текст" (искусственно сформировал для теста, приходит в ответе в json как значение поля. Неправильно декодируется в клиенте, хотя браузер (фарефокс) нормально отображает. Такой способ кодировке я раньше встречал, но забыл, как называется, скорее всего жава-програмеры знакомы. (П.С. На сервере кодировка utf-8)

Comment: Вот такая тестовая программа:

    string source = @"\320\240\321\203\321\201\321\201\320\272\320\270\320\271\321\202\320\265\320\272\321\201\321\202";
    var split = source.Split(new[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var bytes = split.Select(s => (byte)Convert.ToInt32(s, 8));
    var result = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(bytes.ToArray());

получает в `result` строку "Русскийтекст".

Так что у вас строка, кодированная в UTF-8, закодированные байты представлены в восьмеричном виде.

Comment: @VladD, только вот работать эта программка, похоже, будет только для правильного формата данных. 

Иногда она видимо будет выбрасывать исключения, но как привязать его к конкретному месту (ошибка формата) во входных данных?

Comment: @avp: проблемы могут быть вот где:

1. Неверный формат входных данных (строка не бьётся на последовательность цифр и бэкслэши). Это ловится как ошибка в `Convert.ToByte`, нужно вручную обходить split (`foreach (var p in split) { ...`). Восстановить номер байта можно, отсчитав в исходной строке нужное к-во бэкслэшей. (Это сравнительно медленно, но процедура восстановления при ошибке имеет право быть медленной).
2. Байты не складываются в нужную кодировку (невалидный UTF-8): у `Encoding` есть перегрузки, которые возвращают спец. символ на месте нераспознанных символов.

Comment: @VladD, наверное при любом анализе такая программа на шарпе будет все равно короче, чем на Си. 

Например, вот такая

    /*   Convert что-то вроде \040\377... (escaped 3 octal digits) в строку char 
      Input: const char *input, завершается nil или isspace() символом
      Returns: number of bytes in output
      Results: output заполненный байтами, кодированными в input (без trailing nil)
      *uend  адрес байта в input, на котором остановились
    */
    int binostr (const char *input, char *output, int omaxsize, char **uend);

у меня меньше 20 строк не получилась.

Comment: @avp: C# — язык высокого уровня (и хорош в этом), а C — язык низкого уровня (и хорош в этом). Так что сравнивать количество строк между ними — неблагодарное занятие. У меня не получился слишком сжатый результат: https://ideone.com/wBENiX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, эта «кодировка» называется «Octal Escape Sequences».

Этот термин используют в
[Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c583.html), 
 [здесь](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fescape.htm) и еще во многих ссылках  гугла.

Comment: Ага, а кодировка (после трансляции) -- utf8